# ESP on wrong disk with Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, uefi

I have a laptop that came with a HDD and a Windows 8 pre-installed. I've replaced the HDD with an SSD and put the HDD in place of the optical bay with an optibay. I installed a new Windows on the SSD and an Ubuntu afterwards.

My problem is that quite often when booting from GRUB to Windows, I get the error message:

> error: not a valid root device.

This doesn't always occur, but about half the time. When this happens, Windows is still bootable if I go into the UEFI boot settings and change the boot order so that Windows is ahead of Ubuntu (GRUB). In this case, of course, I can only boot to Windows, and if I want to boot Ubuntu, I have to go back to the boot settings and change the order back. Quite annoying.

(This has been occurring for quite a while, but it's just now that I got really fed up with it as I have to frequently switch between the two OS-es.)

I have investigated the problem, and it turns out that for some reason, when I was installed Windows on the SSD, it still decided to use the ESP that was already created on the HDD. Ubuntu also registered itself into that same ESP on sdb1, but also created its own at sda3.

When I'm booted into Ubuntu, /dev/sda3 is mounted to /boot/efi, where there are only the Ubuntu boot files:

```
> ls -lR /boot/efi
/boot/efi:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 feb 13  2016 EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 feb 13  2016 ubuntu

/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu:
total 3444
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     126 aug 20 13:50 grub.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  958328 aug 20 13:50 grubx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1271672 aug 20 13:50 MokManager.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 aug 20 13:50 shimx64.efi
```

sdb1 is not mounted automatically. If I mount it, I can see the boot files of both Ubuntu and Windows (too many files to list all of them):

```
> ll sdb1/EFI/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 mrt 13  2015 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 jan  1  1970 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mrt 13  2015 Boot/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 okt 12  2014 Microsoft/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mrt 13  2015 ubuntu/
```

The `ubuntu` folder here also seems to have all relevant files, except older ones:

```
sdb1/EFI/ubuntu:
total 3444
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     126 jan  8  2016 grub.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  958328 jan  8  2016 grubx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1271672 jan  8  2016 MokManager.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1289424 jan  8  2016 shimx64.efi
```

I'm not very happy with this situation, ideally I'd want the HDD (sdb) to only serve as data storage, so that I can remove it if necessary. This is of course not currently possible, due to the (more complete) ESP being on that disk.

I also suspect that this somehow causes the `error: not a valid root device` problem I described earlier.

How would you suggest I sort out this situation?